# Skype: how to make notifications bigger

Tags: skype

I have a big screen (30 inch) and I usually miss when someone is writing me a message in Skype. That's important because I must notice the message and answer immediately. How can this be solved? Any plugin? I want the IM notifications be really big

Comment: this isn't exactly a web app issue.. but in general you have to provide the OS as well..

Comment: I can move to any OS if this feature works there )))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the way not to miss when a user starts chat with me on Ubuntu (and probably on old versions of Skype for Windows, version 2 I suggest). On the screenshot: If you choose "open a new window in the front", you will never miss an incoming message.[image]

Comment: The option seems to be absent in new versions (using Skype for Windows 6.16)

Answer (score 1):

Only way to do it, is to reduce the screen resolution, that will make all the screen objects bigger. Skype does not support plug-ins that could control the look of notification icons, neither it allows to configure their size from within the app. This is true of cause, for the current version of Skype in october 2011.

Comment: But can I install some script showing a big window on the screen when the message arrives?

Comment: It is possible with custom programming. But I doubt there is such an application, since the market for it would hardly be found. There may be some generic applications, but they wouldn't know how to hook up to a Skype event.